# understanding pg_wal and archiving

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging, archive, archive-log

So I inherited this database. At the very beginning, there were already some files on `pg_wal`.

Then, after some weeks, I do count `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';`, it results : **8182** files.

Looking at the file's timestamp on `pg_wal` directory, I see some new files being created but the number of files stays the same. I am suspecting that the rotation takes place.

Then I observe the `pg_stat_archiver` : `archived_count = **2**; failed_count = 0`

Some 3 hours later, I do count again `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';` It results : **8183**. Obviously a new file is created.

Then I do `pg_stat_archiver` : `archived_count = **3**; failed_count = 0`

```
archived_count last_archived_wal           last_archived_time   failed_count    last_failed_wal  last_failed_time 
3              000000010000009B00000083    22-09-13 13:14:20.   0
stats_reset                          
2022-09-13 08:14:19
```

This database is very low, not busy at all. Sometimes no one access it. But there is logical replication that sync some 300 records once a day to another server.

Here is my settings :

```
max_wal_size : 1024 Mb
min_wal_size : 2048 Mb
wal_keep_segment : 0
wal_rotation : ON
wal_level : logical
wal_compression : ON
archive_on : ON
archive_mode : test ! -f /Archive/%f && cp %p /Archive/%f
archive_timeout : 900
```

Questions :

1. Why does the second count of `pg_wal` increase? I am expecting that it decreases because the archived number increases.
2. If `wal_keep_segment = 0`, why the number of WALs in `pg_wal` never 0 ? In the documentation, it says :

> If wal_keep_segments is zero (the default), the system doesn't keep
> any extra segments for standby purposes,

3. Why the minimum number of WALs, during low period, **does not** = `min_wal_size` + `wal_keep_segment`?

Please enlighten me.

Thank you so much

Comment: Look at the actual file names and time stamps using `pg_ls_waldir()`, or directly using OS tools.  Maybe there is a bunch of garbage left over from some long-ago misadventure that never got cleaned up.

Comment: yes. there were already files on `pg_wal` even with `archive mode = off`. Its been running a year but why the WAL files still hanging around ? Shouldn't they be consumed by the postgres internal system ? @jjanes

Comment: No way to know what happened a year ago unless you have a trail of backups you could troll through, or someone to interrogate.  If someone manually mucked around in the pg_wal directory (particularly the archive_status sub), they could have broken PostgreSQL's ability to clean up or recycle the old files.  In that case, the only way for them to go away is for some brave person to go muck around in pg_wal again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run a `CHECKPOINT` on the primary and see if that deletes some WAL segments (checkpoints happen regularly anyway). Probably, that won't get rid of the WAL segments.

Then, examine the known causes for PostgreSQL to keep around WAL:

- `wal_keep_size` (or `wal_keep_segments` on old versions): you already checked that
- archiver problems (look into `pg_stat_archiver`): you already did that as well
- stale replication slots:

  ```
  SELECT slot_name, slot_type, active, restart_lsn, confirmed_flush_lsn
  FROM pg_replication_slots;
  ```

  Look for slots where `active` is `FALSE` and the LSN is old.

Comment: There are 3 replication : 2 are inactive, 1 active. 

The active replication has `state : streaming; sync_state : async; sent_lsn = write_lsn = replay_lsn = 98/8800C590`. 

I already dropped the inactive replications. And I want to resync the active one. Should I drop the replication and recreate it OR restart the replication ? Thanks @LaurezAlbe

Comment: The active one synchronizes itself, don't worry about it. Drop the inactive replication slots, and your problem is history.

Comment: yes. Thanks. Finally the files in `pg_wal` drops to only 2400+. 

But, out of curiosity, how long does it take for number of WALs to be reduced to 0 when `archiving_mode` is turned off ? I have a couple of WALs that are 1 year old. If archiving is off, no WALs will be kept around. So the postgres internal should eat them all up. Correct ? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Yes, correct. WAL is deleted at the end of a checkpoint. Actually, I would have expected *all* your old WAL segments to go away at that time. I didn't read the code on the exact algorithm, but I would expect your WAL size to go down still more as time goes by, unless there is another obstacle.